# What startup system does ubuntu use?

Tags: startup, init.d

I've seen several ways to add programs or daemons to startup in Ubuntu 12.04 but I am unsure about each method, basically because I don't understand the underlying startup procedure. I need

- A way to run a daemon before login with root as owner
- A way to run a program after the login of one user
- A way to run a program after the login of any user
- A way to run a program after the whole gnome environment is set up

Answer (score 5):

[upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

[This guide is fairly useful](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

Answer (score 0):

The below link maybe useful to you. I am also confused with startup procedure.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto